# O Radio Button não muda o texto

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Eu criei um projeto simples, e percebi que o `RadioButton` não muda o texto ao rotacionar a tela. Criei 2 funções uma chamado `setText()` e a outra `setText2()` com conteúdos diferentes, a `setText()` é chamado quando `savedInstance` é nulo e a outra quando não é nulo, o android entra na `setText2()` normalmente e seta o texto, mas não muda visualmente.

Tentei dar request e o invalidate e não resolveu, seria um bug do componente?

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment {
    private RadioButton optA, optB,optC,optD;
    private static final String TAG = "SampleFragment";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView");
        View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample,container,false);
        optA =  (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.optA);
        optB =  (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.optB);
        optC =  (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.optC);
        optD =  (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.optD);
        Button btnSetText = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_settext);
        btnSetText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setText2();
            }
        });
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            setText();
        }
        else{
            setText2();
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG,"onPause");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG,"onResume");
    }
    private void setText2(){
        optA.setText("A1");
        optB.setText("B2");
        optC.setText("C3");
        optD.setText("D4");
    }
    private void setText(){
        optA.setText("A");
        optB.setText("B");
        optC.setText("C");
        optD.setText("D");
    }

}
```

Github do projeto: https://github.com/guilhermehrcosta/Radio-Group-Bug

Comment: Coloque o código directamente na pergunta.

Comment: Pronto! Coloquei :D

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa enviar uma mensagem para sua interface de usuário informando que está querendo atualizar um componente.

Você pode usar um Handler da seguinte forma:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // SETA O TEXTO NO SEU COMPONENTE AQUI...
        }
    });
```

O Handler deve ser iniciado no seu contexto, ou seja, na Activity que chama seu fragmento.

exemplo:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Comment: Beleza, agora te pergunto pq o setText() funciona, e ao rotacionar a tela o setText2() não funciona, é um bug meio doido mesmo. Eu resolvi colocando um view.post(new Runnable());

Comment: Isso mesmo Guilherme, a diferença de usar o handler.post(new Runnable) para o view.post(new Runable) é que o handler atualiza o contexto todo e a view apenas aquela view do fragmento em questão. É a mesma solução que te passei, você poderia até colocar no próprio TextView tipo myTextView.post(new Runnable)) etc.